# Simulink simulating audio extremely slow

Tags: matlab, audio, simulink

I've creating following model:
[image]

The simulation works as expected, but the speed of it is immensely slow. When listening to the output, it's just a small noise every once in a while, at the `T` indicator barely increases by 0.005/s. I understand the software has to run audio samples through the algorithm constantly, but the simulation being this slow makes me concern about when I have to use it in practice, as it then has to be used on a Microphone on a Raspberry Pi in real-time.

Am I using some bad blocks, is my signal set-up in a bad manner, what can I do to increase the performance of the system?

EDIT - Info from my profiler:
[image]

Comment: You should read more samples from your sources. 2 is tiny for audio. Try increasing that to something like 1024.

Comment: @Navan Ah yes, I've seen increase in performance if I change that paramenter, however it makes it almost impossible to analyze my algorithm using Scopes without the scopes crashing or being very slow. Edit: Actually just tried changing my sample read to 1024, exact same result, slow simulation.

Comment: Those blocks in your model should be able to run in real time with a size of 1024. I do not know what else is making it slow. Try running with simulink profiler to see where most time is spent.

Comment: Added the profiler to the post. I fail to see anything rather unexpected, but other eyes might see different. I tried using a 44100Hz sample instead of 48000Hz, which increased the performance a bit, but not enough for the sound to be understandable. Any ideas why this has that kind of effect?

Comment: I also do not see much in the profiler results. A simple check to try would be to directly connect your audio player to the switch block and see whether that plays properly. Then add few blocks at a time to see when the problem occurs.